# ASymptote export animation as mp4

Tags: asymptote

I want to make a series of images titled `anim0.png`, `anim1.png` corresponding to different frames of an animation. As I understand, the 
[examples page](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/animations/index.html) typically outputs a pdfmovie which can only be viewed with the Adobe PDF viewer. And Adobe PDF viewer is available only on Windows and not Linux.

So can I instead output the animation to mp4 format?

Comment: In the source code of the page you link to there are some examples, e.g., in `wheel.asy` the line `a.movie(BBox(0.25cm),loops=10,delay=250);` produces an animated gif, and in `externalmovie.asy` the line `asy("mp4","wheel")` produces an mp4 movie from the animation in `wheel.asy`. There are several conversion steps in the background, make sure you have `convert` and `ffmpeg` available and the right permissions for ImageMagick (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42928765/convertnot-authorized-aaaa-error-constitute-c-readimage-453). Direct `.png` output should also be possible.